# How to get 7 days data from multiple table

Tags: mysql, select

Get 7 days data from multiple tables in mysql.

This is my select statement:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM chain_management UNION 
SELECT * FROM adagio_accounting_suite UNION
SELECT * FROM billquick UNION 
SELECT * FROM budgetingdb UNION 
SELECT * FROM chain_management UNION
SELECT * FROM accountpayable
WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY curtime DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM chain_management UNION 
SELECT * FROM adagio_accounting_suite UNION
SELECT * FROM billquick UNION 
SELECT * FROM budgetingdb UNION 
SELECT * FROM chain_management UNION
SELECT * FROM accountpayable) as XYZ
WHERE DATE >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) ORDER BY curtime DESC";
```